# My code is adding a space between the string and the variable? Why is it doing that?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So when I execute this code, it adds a space between names[i] and the string?

```
var names = ["Bob", "Daniel", "John", "Jimmy", "Joseph"]

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
    console.log("I know someone called",names[i])
}
```

I'm new to this.

Comment: `console.log(names.join(''))`

Answer (score 5):

That's just the behaviour of `console.log`. Each parameter you pass will be separated by a space, and is expected (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console))  - if you don't want the space, try:

```
console.log("I know someone called" + names[i]);
```

By using the `+`, you are directly concatenating the strings and ensuring there is no space